# How to autoplay audio when the countdown timer is finished?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I want to play a sound after the countdown timer is done.
Normally I will do it using this peace of code

```
   var audio = new Audio('path to file.mp3');
   audio.play();
```

But I get the following error **Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.**

The thing is ... Google it self is doing it using a HTML5 audio tag

If you type `countdown timer` into google search field it should show you the widget that plays a sound after the countdown timer is finished.

Here is how Googles timer look like, if you guys don't know what I'm talking about :)

[image: google widget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making you click this "START" button, they ask for an user gesture and thus have marked their document as approved-by-user to play audio. This means they are not subject for chrome's [autoplay policies](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/autoplay#sites-canvas-main-content) anymore.

Now, Safari by default is even stricter than Chrome here, and a simple click on the document doesn't work: in this browser you need to start the playback from the user-event itself.

So in your case, it won't work, even if you did start the countdown from a click like Google.

The solution is then to start the playback from the click event, and to pause it immediately after. Doing so, your Element will be marked as approved-by-user and you will ave full control over it.

```js
const audio = new Audio("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3");
let time = 5;

btn.onclick = e => {
  // mark our audio element as approved by the user
  audio.play().then(() => { // pause directly
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  });
  countdown();
  btn.disabled = true;
};


function countdown() {
  pre.textContent = --time;
  if(time === 0) return onend();
  setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}


function onend() {
  audio.play(); // now we're safe to play it
  time = 5;
  btn.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">start countdown</button><br>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks mate :)